# How to differentiate between ApplicationContext and Context?

Tags: java, android

I have a Android method which receives instance of Context object, I want to differentiate if the passed context object is returned using one of the following methods

- [View.getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29):  Returns the context the view is currently running in.  Usually the currently active Activity.
- [Activity.getApplicationContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getApplicationContext%28%29):  Returns the context for the entire application (the process all the Activities are running inside
  of).  Use this instead of the current Activity context if you need a
  context tied to the lifecycle of the entire application, not just the
  current Activity.

Since both methods return instance of Context object but with different capabilities, how can I differentiate if passed context object is Activity Context or Application Context ?

Comment: Usually, the better answer is to have two entry points. In your case, your one method taking a `Context` would turn into two methods, taking an `Activity` and an `Application`, for example.

Comment: well idea was to keep it simple for external developer or client application

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Since both methods return instance of Context object but with
>   different capabilities, how can I differentiate if passed context
>   object is Activity Context or Application Context ?

you can check with `instanceof`. It allows to check if the object is of a certain type. E.g.

```
 if (context instanceof Activity) {

 }
```

Comment: Does this also mean you can use `instanceof Application` to check whether it's `getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: @PPartisan, easy test `Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "am I Application " + (getApplicationContext() instanceof Application));`

Comment: I forgot to mention third case, context could be instance of ContextWrapper , so if  instaceof Application works then it covers all the cases

Comment: (getApplicationContext() instanceof Application)  returns true :), you can update your answer for this case

Answer (score 2):

```
if (yourContext != yourContext.applicationContext) {
 
}
```

tested with passing `applicationContext` as `yourContext` and others.